# Why is my window subview showing, but not handling any touches?

Tags: iphone, ios, subview

I have my UIWindow structured in Interface Builder as:

- window

  - drawingView (custom UIView)
  - toolbar (UIToolbar)

Where the drawingView handles touches using touchesBegan etc. However, when I try and add 'someView' (a custom UIView) which has UIButtons on it as a subview of window, the buttons don't receive any of the touches.

I create 'someView' with:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:someView];
```

'someView' displays fine on top of the drawingView, but the touches don't seem to register at all, and get passed through to drawingView. Why is that?

Another odd thing is that the backgroundColor of someView always seems to be clear, even if I set it to something else programatically or in IB.

Also, when I create someView using

```
[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:someView];
```

it works fine, handling touches and all. The reason I want to add it as a subview is because I want a more general way of adding someView, that is works on the iphone as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a fix (in a hackish kind of way).

I had to add 'someView' as a subview of drawingView, which appears on top of drawView when shown, and allows me to programatically set up someView with UIButtons, which receives touches.

I think it's because drawView is an OpenGL view, that overrides layerClass which does something funky with how the views are arranged to obtain touches. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `userInteractionEnabled` flag is set on all parents of the view that needs to receive touches.

Comment: The userInteractionEnabled flag is set for everything, seeing as the drawingView accepts touches fine. Also, when I create someView as a popupViewController, it works fine too.

Comment: Are you trying to receive touches on a UIControl or UIView element? UIView won't work, as far as I know.

Comment: UIControl through a UIButton, which is on a UIView

Comment: No more ideas, sorry. But I would be really interested in knowing the cause, if you figure it out.